# after load page with ajax form submition not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

my form submit after load page with ajax not working
my code for load page :

problem : after load ajax form as modalbox   elements

```js
function account_list(url)
{
 $.ajax({
  type: 'get',
  url: url,
  beforeSend: function() {
   parsysm.loading(1);
  },
  success: function(data) {
   $('div#option-id-1').slideUp('slow', function(){
    $(this).html(data).slideDown('slow');
   });
  },
  error: function() {
   alert('Error Report!');
  },
  complete: function() {
   parsysm.loading(0);
  }
 })
}
```

and load page action :

```html
<form id="form-options-show" class="form-horizontal ">
 <div class="form-body">

<form id="form-options-show" class="fast-panel">
چینش&nbsp;&raquo;&nbsp;
<select class="inputcl1" name="order" size="1">
<option value="DESC"[desc] selected="selected"[/desc]>نزولی</option>
<option value="ASC"[asc] selected="selected"[/asc]>صعودی</option>
</select>
&nbsp;&nbsp;تعداد کاربران در صفحه&nbsp;&raquo;&nbsp;
<input name="total" class="inputcl1" type="text" style="width:25px;text-align:center" value="{total}" maxlength="3" />
&nbsp;&nbsp;جستجو&nbsp;&raquo;&nbsp;
<input name="search" class="inputcl1" type="text" style="width:150px" value="{search}" dir="ltr" />
[pages]
&nbsp;&nbsp;صفحه&nbsp;&raquo;&nbsp;
<select name="page" class="inputcl1" size="1">
[for pages]<option value="{number}"[selected] selected="selected"[/selected]>{number}</option>[/for pages]
</select>
[/pages]
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input class="btn green" type="button" value="نمایش" onclick="account_list('{admin-page}&addon=account&'+parsysm.serialize('form-options-show'))" />
<input name="sort" type="hidden" value="{sort}" />
</form>
```

but after load page modalbox action not working -> modal box code :

```html
 <div class="modal fade" id="portlet-sms{id}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
     <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
       <h4 class="modal-title">ارسال پیامک به {name-show}</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
                             <div id="sms-ajax{id}"></div>
                            <form id="sms-form{id}" onsubmit="sms_send({id});return false">
                            <input type="tel" name="singlesms[number]" value="{mobile}" class="form-control"  maxlength="11" placeholder="09-- --- -- --" disabled /><br>
                            <textarea class="form-control" name="singlesms[msg]" placeholder="متن خود را وارد نمایید"></textarea>
                            
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
                         <input type="submit" class="btn blue" value="ارسال پیام"  />
       
       <button type="button" class="btn default" data-dismiss="modal">بستن</button></form>
      </div>
     </div>
     <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
   </div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Your question is without a clear problem statement and lacks information...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question clearly but seems like you are trying to replace existing form with new form returned in the data.

You'll need to write listener on document which listens for form and registers submit event to it. Something like below:

```js
$(document).on("submit", "form", callbackFunction());
```

Answer (score 0):

my data form after load page with ajax are :

```html
<form id="sms-form17920" onsubmit="sms_send(17920);return false"></form>
```

form data element under this code !!!